# vite react dynamic image url

Tags: reactjs, vite

hello guys i have problem with vite react dynamic images url not loading correctly  and thats my component

```
 <Flex>
      {data?.map((tag) => (
        <Box key={tag._id}>
          <Image w="150px" h="150px" src={`http:localhost:5000/${tag.imageUrl}`}></Image>
        </Box>
      ))}
    </Flex>
```

when i check the network tab i see that the url of the client is added to the image url

```
http://localhost:3000/localhost:5000/uploads/1623642756947--Capture.PNG
```

in create react app maybe we can use `reqiure()` to fix that but i dont know how to fix that in vite  and adding `reqiure()` throw an error

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use the dynamic URL pattern via template literal. This is what it may look like for your case:

```
function getImgUrl(name) {
   return new URL(`${name}`, import.meta.url).href
}

<Flex>
  {data?.map((tag) => (
    <Box key={tag._id}>
      <Image w="150px" h="150px" src={ getImgUrl(tag.imageUrl) }></Image>
    </Box>
  ))}
</Flex>
```

Answer (score 0):

> when i check the network tab i see that the url of the client is added to the image url
> `http://localhost:3000/localhost:5000/uploads/1623642756947--Capture.PNG`

This is because **importing a static asset** in `vite` return **the resolved public URL** when it is served.

This *excerpt from the offical doc* say *(adapted according your question)*:

- For example, `http//:localhost:5000/${tag.imageUrl}` will be `/http:localhost:5000/uploads/1623642756947--Capture.PNG` during development,
- and become `/assets/http:localhost:5000/uploads/1623642756947--Capture.PNG` in the production build.

The solution is to use the `server.proxy` option of `vite config` to **forward** your dynamic assets requests to the desired server, in `vite.config.js` add:

```
  server: {
    proxy: {
      // forward `/uploads/` endpoint to -> `http://localhost:5000/uploads/`
      '^/uploads': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5000/'
      }
    }
  }
```

So in your component, `Image` should be declared like that :

`` <Image w="150px" h="150px" src={`${tag.imageUrl}`}></Image> ``

Now when you hit
`http://localhost:3000/uploads/1623642756947--Capture.PNG`

The asset (image) will be loaded from to `http://localhost:5000/uploads/1623642756947--Capture.PNG`

You can get more information about `Static Assets Handling` [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#static-asset-handling) and `vite proxy options` [here](https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-proxy).

**Solution tested and working ✔**