# Vite/React/Vercel images not loading

Tags: reactjs, vite, vercel

I'm using Vite to build out some React projects and noticed that when I deployed on Vercel, the images don't load. Example: https://job-list-site.vercel.app/
In the console they all have a 404.

The images are all svg [image: images file] but imported from a local json file (see image). They are then referenced as so:

```
import data from '../../../data.json';
<img src={jobItem.logo} alt="Company logo" />
```

I was looking at this [vite react dynamic image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67995027/vite-react-dynamic-image-url) but had no luck, any other suggestions? Thank you in advance!

[image: json file]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after playing around with this, I placed the images in the public folder, ran npm run build + preview and it was working.

Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in React project which is created by Vite. The image code was like this:

```
<img src={`/avatar-pictures/avatar(${Number(data.id )}).png`} alt={data.title} />
```

The public folder is like this:
https://prnt.sc/FoDQhTI3MVwi

Project is working fine in vercel.