# Images will not load after a certain page in vite react project

Tags: reactjs, vite, create-react-app

I am building an e-commerce website, the problem is that after a certain page, images do not load anymore and I always get the alt text data.
It is not an issue with the image path as even if I hard code an image src, the image does not load. On the homepage, navbar and general product pages, the images are present, its only once you click on a product and go to its specific page, the images do not load. If you reload the website on the specific product page, the image in the navbar also does not load.

I tried to see if the dynamic data from my JSON file was incorrect, but the alt data was matching the product that had been clicked. That is why I put a constant src from one photo to see if it could load any image. I have tried deleting the cache to see if it would enable faster loading and that the photos would load, but no luck.

[Here is a snapshot of one of the JSON files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAp2s.png)

[This is the app component where the JSON data is fetched and passed into the "Boots" and "BootItem" component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrwWk.png)

[Boot component where the bootData is passed into the boot list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynFeY.png)

[Boot data mapped into separate items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHO9K.png)

[The boot data item card, all the photos work in this component, there are no issues here, when you click on the card item, you are taken the the BootItem component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCKpq.png)

[The boot data has been passed here directly from the app, the issue is that the images do not load on this page, only that alt text, the other boot information is present on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06Ig9.png)

[Here is a screenshot of the mapped data and the images are working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlSVr.jpg)

[This is the bootItem page where the photos do not load, the logo in the nav does not work, and the boot that was clicked does not show the boot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnwwX.png)

Comment: Hey, can you please add the code where you're trying to display the image ?

Comment: Can you add your code?? or read this article : https://stackoverflow.com/q/75934418/20149822  Hope that helps!!

Comment: @p4avinash I have included the code snapshots in the hyperlinks

Comment: @Janani I have included the code snapshots in the hyperlinks